# Designing SNS receiver in python script

Tags: python-3.x, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns, boto3

Hi I am new to Python as well as AWS SNS services.
I want to develop a Python utility which would perform a role of subscriber as well as publisher to automate some simulations.
I am stuck where I need to design endpoint which would act as a SNS message receiver.
Could you guys please guide me on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda is a nice service for such scenarios and also it is quite cheap so will keep your AWS bills low.
You need publisher and subscriber for SNS in python so use AWS Lambda which will give you a nice connectivity with AWS SNS and there are few samples for subscribers which will help you in configuring the same. 
So now your events get into AWS SNS and through subscription of lambda you can invoke Lambda function and take the action accordingly.

Event ---> SNS ---> Lambda Subscriber ---> Python Functions

[Here](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1VE917Z8J4UDY/Invoking-AWS-Lambda-functions-via-Amazon-SNS) is a nice reference for the same.

For publisher, you can use scheduled Lambda Function which will keep on pooling for some event to occur and then depending upon event you can send the notification to same SNS endpoint or different.

Event <--(Pooling)- Lambda Publisher(Cron Based) --(Event Occurred)-> SNS

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduledevents-example.html) is the AWS Tutorial for the same.

I hope this helps.

PS: Just keep in mind that maximum runtime for any Lambda function should not exceed certain limit which is 5 mins currently.